# How to import a terraform data source for an aws_organizations_organizaation

Tags: terraform

I have a simple aws_organizations_organization data source

```
data "aws_organizations_organization" "my_org" {
    name = "my_org"
}
```

I am trying to import the datasource into my state.

Expected
run `terraform import data.aws_organizations_organization my_org`. Then the datasource is imported properly.

Actual
run `terraform import data.aws_organizations_organization my_org`. Then I get the error

```
 Error: Invalid address
│ 
│   on <import-address> line 1:
│    1: data.aws_organizations_organization
│ 
│ Resource specification must include a resource type and name.
```

What is wrong with this command?

Comment: You are trying to import a resource to a data. You need to import a resource to a resource.

Comment: How do you import a datasource?

Comment: You do not import a data. It is read only, and therefore would and could not be stored in state.